Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer', Unsupported Database: MariaDB 10.6 after migration to spring boot 3.0.0

Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unsupported Database: MariaDB 10.6 after migration to spring boot 3.0.0


flyway-core: 9.2.1
org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client: 3.0.7

i'm using FlywayAutoConfiguration of spring boot.
what can be the issue?

Try a newer flyway version - they don't keep incompatibilities for long and 9.2.1 is almost 2 years old.
